# Getting Attribute Data For Return Value of .NET Method

Tags: c#, reflection

I can call GetCustomAttributesData on a MemberInfo, which is nice because I know which constructor was called to initialize the attribute and what named arguments were used.

If I put [return: ...] on a method to attribute the return value, I can't get to GetCustomAttributesData. The only thing I can use is ReturnTypeCustomAttributes, which gets me the attributes, not their data.

Is there any way to get the attribute data via reflection for a return value of a method? Note: using GetCustomAttributesData on the MethodInfo object doesn't return attributes for the return value.

Comment: can you show the code that you are using so that we can understand exactly what it is you are trying to do..? also according to `MSDN the GetCustomAttributesData` returns `IList` so you should be able to get something returned.. perhaps from there you will need to iterate through the List using a foreach loop

Comment: Note that it's the *method* that has the attribute - not the returned value itself.

Comment: Perhaps off topic, but why on earth would you want to do something like this? Are you doing you part to keep the global software pletora down?

Comment: @vidstige It seems like a reasonable thing to want to do. You want to find all methods that have the return value annotated with an attribute in a reflection only context. From a cursory glance at the reflection APIs I don't see how you get the CustomAttributeData objects for this scenario.

Comment: I'm writing a mocking library, and I want to add all attribute annotations to generic parameters, parameters and return values for a method I'm mocking. That's why I need to know.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out:

```
x.ReturnParameter.GetCustomAttributesData()
```