# How to get return binding Attribute for Azure FunctionApp binding

Tags: function, azure, reflection, model-binding

I have function:

```
[FunctionName("test-function")]
        [return: ServiceBus("topic-name", Connection = "connection-string")]
        public static Task<Message> TestFunction([TimerTrigger("%TimerSchedule%")]TimerInfo timer, ILogger log)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new Message());
        }
```

How can I get *ServiceBus* attribute through reflecion as it is not part of methods CustomAttributes collection?

Answer (score 1):

[Getting Attribute Data For Return Value of .NET Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085515/getting-attribute-data-for-return-value-of-net-method)

```
x.ReturnParameter.GetCustomAttributesData()
```